How are pad impedance discontinuities precisely compensated for in high speed PCB layouts?
I stumbled across a recommendation in an 850MHz opamp datasheet that said the following:

All ground and power planes under the input and output pins must be cleared of copper to prevent the formation of parasitic capacitance to ground. A single mounting pad on the SOIC footprint can add as much as 0.2pF of capacitance to ground if the ground plane is not cleared from under the mounting pads.

(paraphrased from ADA4857 datasheet, page 19)
I was already aware of this general practice, but it started me thinking about what happens to the return currents as the signal wavefront propagates into the pad geometry, and that led me to conclude that what they're really talking about here is simply an impedance discontinuity caused by the pad being physically wider than the nominal trace width for a 50Ω characteristic impedance trace. Essentially you've got too much capacitance and too little inductance, so Z₀ drops.
This answer confirms that line of thinking, and clarifies why voiding also affects the inductance:

The bigger SMD pads will act as a larger capacitor area, in other words, around your SMD device you have a lower impedance transmission line. We want to avoid this, so we can do two things: make the increase of capacitance as low as possible, or increase the amount of inductance.
This solution achieves both: Removing the ground plane under the device will reduce the capacitance created by the bigger pads. In addition, you increase the loop area the current needs to take in that area, which in turn increase the inductance. Both help in increasing the impedance again.

(Answer to "When to Remove the Ground Plane under SMD components for High-Speed Signals?", written by Joren Vaes, licensed under CC BY-SA 4.0)
However, it is clear to me that simply removing the ground (and potentially power, on lower layers) copper under the pad, with the void having the same size and shape as the pad, is a pretty arbitrary approach chosen for its simplicity rather than precision, and the fact that you can do it without needing to use (or afford) a field solver. For 850MHz a simple equally-sized void almost certainly suffices, but for a very high speed system (e.g. modern TbE stuff or mmWave) it seems rather implausible that such a simple rule of thumb could be adopted without suffering significant insertion loss.
My educated guess is that a lot of it comes down to adjusting the size of the void (keepout) on the reference plane to adjust the amount of coupling that occurs between the pad and that plane, widening the void to increase impedance and narrowing it to decrease impedance, but I can also imagine that there are more complex ground plane geometries (e.g. different void shapes, maybe cross-hatching or other thin structures) used for very demanding applications. I'm interested to know what kinds of geometries designers have come up with when compensating for these pad discontinuities.
In short: what kind of PCB layout tricks are used for fine control of impedance when dealing with voiding under pads in high speed designs? Are there any key reference materials (e.g. appnotes) for this topic? To be clear, I'm primarily interested in details relatign to the actual PCB copper geometry rather than active compensation (e.g. de-embedding). I'm also already familiar with topics like fiberglass weave effects and copper roughness control.

The impedance discontinuity created by a pad at 850 MHz is ~ 1/100th of a wavelength and so can be ignored.  Essentially the pad, the pin and the IC inputs are lumped elements, so you can treat them as a total capacitance.  Removing the grounds reduces that lumped capacitance, which is what the datasheet is trying to achieve.

How to compensate the PCB pads for some component depends on what kind of compensation the component needs. The compensation is not identical and needs to be different depending on if the component is a chip in some package and in which package it is, or is it a connector. Components always have some kind of pads and some kind of internal wiring to those pads and then the signal goes somewhere, like some on-die structure which terminates it or in case of a connector, mates with the plug and connects to a transmission line of some sort.
